# Python type hint for (any) class

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

I want to type hint the following function:

```
def get_obj_class(self) -> CLASS_TYPE:
  return self.o.__class__
```

- `CLASS_TYPE` should denote `class`es.
- `self.o` could be of any type determined at runtime.

---

On a similar note, if I have a function `f(cls: CLASS_TYPE)` which returns an instance of `cls`, is there a way to type hint the return value appropriately?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd recommend using a combination of [`TypeVar`](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html), to indicate that your `self.o` value could be any arbitrary type, and [`Type`](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects), in the following way:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, o: T) -> None:
        self.o = o

    def get_obj_class(self) -> Type[T]:
        return type(self.o)

def accept_int_class(x: Type[int]) -> None:
    pass

i = MyObj(3)
foo = i.get_obj_class()
accept_int_class(foo)    # Passes

s = MyObj("foo")
bar = s.get_obj_class()
accept_int_class(bar)    # Fails
```

If you want the type of `o` to be even more dynamic, you could explicitly or implicitly give it a type of `Any`.

---

Regarding your latter question, you'd do:

```
def f(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
    return cls()
```

Note that you need to be careful when instantiating your class -- I don't remember what Pycharm does here, but I do know that mypy currently does not check to make sure you're calling your `__init__` function correctly/with the right number of params.

(This is because T could be anything, but there's no way to hint what the constructor ought to look like, so performing this check would end up being either impossibly or highly difficult.)

Comment: I really dislike the need to create a _named_ TypeVar object everytime you want to construct a custom type. I think in my situation I'd rather stick to `type`. But thank you for introducing this

Comment: @nO_OnE_910 -- you could reuse the same TypeVar variable when defining your generic classes and functions. You might perhaps find that a bit less distasteful since you're introducing only a single named TypeVar object (that you then reuse) instead of one per each generic class or function.

Answer (score 16):

For Python >=3.7, use [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) (see also [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/)):

```
def get_obj_class(self) -> type:
    return self.o.__class__
```

For Python <3.7, use [`typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type):

```
def get_obj_class(self) -> typing.Type:
    return self.o.__class__
```

Comment: + for simplicity, although `typing.TypeVar` seems like the proper solution

Answer (score 1):

What about [`typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type)?

That seems to fit since `__class__` should always return a type.

```
import typing

def test(t: object) -> typing.Type:
    return t.__class__

class Dummy(object):
    pass

test(Dummy())
```

To your second question: that should be a [generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types).

Comment: Why `typing.Type` and not just `type`?

Comment: @nO_OnE_910 I prefer to use the typing module to keep a coherent style. Most of my returns are typing.X, so it just seems more natural for me