# How to setup python typing for a type argument

Tags: python, typing, dynamic-typing

I would like to properly add typing for Python types passed as arguments. E.g. let us assume that we would like to add typing to the following function:

```
def do_something_based_on_types(
    ...
    type_name: str,
    str_to_type_mapping: Dict[str, Any], # what instead of Any?
):
    ...
    object = str_to_type_mapping[type_name]()
    ...
```

where we would like to pass a mapping from `str` to type based on which we would like construct an object of selected class. What is a proper typing for this scenario (instead of `Any` used in a code sample).

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question what exactly you're looking for, but I suspect probably doing either `Dict[str, Callable[[], object]]` or `Dict[str, Type[object]]` might be what you want.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44325153, as that question is about a single dynamic attribute type based on an `__init__` parameter, not a type mapping that contains multiple different types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is very dynamic of nature. Since the main purpose of Python type annotations is supporting *static* analysis, there are limits to what they can provide for us here. However, I do think we can do better than `Any`!

(Note: to prevent confusion, I will refer to the variable in your snippet named `object` as `my_object`, when I use `object`, I mean the Python type).

#### Using [typing.Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type)

Since you mention the values in the provided dictionary are supposed to be types  that can be initiated, a reasonable type annotation would be either `Dict[str, Type[object]]` or `Dict[str, Type]`, where the latter is equivalent to `Dict[str, Type[Any]]`. The first is the most restrictive, and will limit what the type checker will allow you to do on your `my_object` variable. The second is only marginally better than the plain `Any`, although it does warn the caller when they accidentally provide an instance instead of a type.

#### Or [typing.Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable)?

From the snippet you provided, the only way the dictionary value is used is to create a new instance. A type is not the only thing that can do this. Actually, any callable (a plain function, a class method) that takes zero arguments and returns an object would suffice as well. So using `Callable[[], object]` would allow more flexibility to the caller of the function and also warn when a type is passed that doesn't have a zero-argument constructor. I would prefer this over `Type` as it seems both safer and more in the spirit of Pythons duck-typing.

#### Something better than plain object?

Both solutions have the limitation that inside your function, we don't know anything about the type of `my_object`. In the general case we are 'forced' to do `isinstance` checks every time we do an operation not supported by the object type. But, maybe in your use case a single dictionary isn't supposed to contain just any type. It could be that:

1. All types have a base class in common, say `MyBase`.
2. All types are supposed to support a common set of operations (methods or attributes).

In case (1) we can replace the `object` type with the type `MyBase`. The type checker should be able that operations supported by `MyBase` are safe to use, and warn when the provided dictionary contains other types.

For case (2), [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#Typing.Protocol) can help us. You can define a custom protocol with the operations you would require and add that one to the type annotation:

```py
class MyCustomProto(Protocol):
    foo: int
    def bar(self) -> str: ...
```

Now the type checker should know that `my_object` should have the integer attribute 
`foo` and a method `bar` that returns a string. Note that `Protocol` got added to Python 3.8, and is available for previous versions via the [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) package.

#### Dict vs. typing.Mapping

Not directly related to your question, but if you only use the dictionary to read, you should consider replacing the `Dict` with the `Mapping` type. This allows the caller to provide any mapping type other than dict subclasses (unlikely to happen in practice). But more importantly, it warns you when accidentally modifying the supplied mapping, which can result in hard to find bugs. My final suggestion would therefor be `Mapping[str, Callable[[], <X>]`, with `<X>` being one of `object`, `MyCustomProto` or `MyBase`.