# Python: typing a generic function that receives a type and returns an instance of that type

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting

I want to add typing to a Python function that takes in a type as an argument (actually, a subtype of a specific class), and return an instance of that type. Think a factory that takes in the specific type as an argument, e.g.:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Animal)

def make_animal(animal_type: Type[T]) -> T:  # <-- what should `Type[T]` be?
    return animal_type()
```

(obviously this is a very simplistic example, but it demonstrates the case)

This feels like something that should be possible, but I couldn't find how to properly type-hint this.

Comment: Some related questions: [Python Typing: declare return value type based on function argument - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202691/python-typing-declare-return-value-type-based-on-function-argument), [Python type hint for (any) class - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325153/python-type-hint-for-any-class)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure what your question is, the code you posted is perfectly valid Python code. There is [`typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) that does exactly what you want:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

class Animal: ...
class Snake(Animal): ...

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Animal)

def make_animal(animal_type: Type[T]) -> T:
    return animal_type()

reveal_type(make_animal(Animal))  # Revealed type is 'main.Animal*'
reveal_type(make_animal(Snake))   # Revealed type is 'main.Snake*'
```

See mypy output on [mypy-play](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=58887b116c7f2b7596674dbf2b4bfdbd).

Comment: I'm not sure why I missed that, thank you

Comment: I guess the only thing that might be tricky is knowing that in `make_animal(Snake)`, the typevar `T` is inferred as `Snake` and not, say, `Animal`.

Comment: Note that this stops working as soon as either class has an @abstractmethod

Comment: @Sigmatics Could you elaborate? If the class has un-overridden abstract methods then yes, this will result in a typing error, but that's because it's incorrect to construct objects of an abstract class. If `Animal` is abstract but `Snake` isn't, then `make_animal(Snake)` still type-checks.

Comment: @Andrew That's correct. Although I'd argue that if you really want it to be `Animal`, you should just annotate it as `type[Animal]` instead. If there's other classes in the hierarchy between `Animal` and `Snake`, then it's not well-defined to return anything in between.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this?

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Type


class Animal:
    ...


def make_animal(animal_type: Type[Animal]) -> Animal:
    return animal_type()
```